# AWS ECS Service restarting bevause of failed Target Group healthcheck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a .net core API which runs inside a Docker container.
This container got deployed to the Amazon ECR where I run it with a Task definition (works already)

- snipet from my Task definition

> ```
>  "portMappings": [
>     {
>       "hostPort": 50598,
>       "protocol": "tcp",
>       "containerPort": 50598
>     }
>   ],
> ```

When I start the service, the task runs and it works fine. I get my public IP where I can check if my calls are available:
[image]

- HTTP 401 is ok because the call checks for a valid token

[image]

[image]

The problem is when I try to add a Load balancer with a target group.

For this I delete my old service and create a new one with a Load Balancer and Target group
[image]

After I start my service like this the Target Group health check response with a "Request Timeout" and keeps restarting my service.
When I check for the public IP of the API it still works, only when I try to access my API
through the loadbalancer it doesn't work.

Target Group:
[image]

Lb:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting request timeout likely because the security group attached to the task is not allowing inbound access from the load balancer nodes.

By default even if all nodes fail health checks the load balancer will attempt to forward to all nodes, which with a failed inbound evaluation would cause the timeout.

As long as the host allows port `50598` to the load balancer no timeout should occur, if you're using an ALB you can add a source as the security group attached to the load balancer.

Once this access is working, you will need to ensure your health checks are successful for the HTTP status code and path.

It is also worth noting for an Application Load Balancer you can use ranges from `200` - `499`, whereas for a Network Load Balancer it can only have health checks from `200` - `399`.

Your target group must be configured to run on port `50598` too, it is currently targeted port `80`.

**Update**

The application appeared to be running on port `80`. Configuration for the target group and task was updated to use the port. This then began working again.

Comment: I now allow all traffic for my Security group and instead of a timeout I get a 502 now

Comment: This would mean whilst the firewall is now working the application is failing. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-502-issues :)

Comment: The application seems to work, I can use the public IP as endpoint... till it restarts^^

Comment: It'll restart because of the 502 in load balancer. ECS monitors the load balancer health

Comment: The 502 needs to be resolved, can you forward a screenshot of your listener and the target configuration?

Comment: I edited my post, the last pictures are from the lb and target group

Comment: Your target group port is 80, this should also be 50598

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217081/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-christoph).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `401` in the Healthcheck **Success codes** and it should work. As you can define multiple HTTP status codes in the health check of the target group.

[image]

Also to deal with **"Request Timeout"**, allow ECS instance Port `50598` from LB

Comment: I already added the Health check parameters, Path: /api/user/areYouLoggedIn, Success codes: 401. I will check the load balancer Ports again

Comment: No ALB SG is fine, you need to allow Ec2 instance port to make it working, that is why you are getting timeout.

Comment: I now added a security rule for allowing all traffic. I don´t get a timeout anymore, but I get a 502.

Comment: 502 mean backend application is not running. check the application.

Comment: It is restarting over and over again. I can still check the Public IP of the task and it works, but the service keeps restarting

Comment: can you check event tab in ecs service plus healthcheck event? it might be because of service health check failure.

Comment: in the evente tab it logs: 
service papasmuenzen-backend-service-test (port 50598) is unhealthy in target-group backend-test-tg due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [502]).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217080/discussion-between-adiii-and-christoph).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs for my service I found the following reason for stopping it

> service *my-service* (port 80) is unhealthy in target-group *my-target-group* due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [302]).

And Http code 302 is for performing URL redirection.

Since there is nothing wrong with the service itself and it is the failed health checkup that the task is stopped and restarted. I changed the health checkup configuration to consider `200(default) and 302` response code as success. And it is fixed now.

But not sure if this is the right fix for this.